# Issue with Camera on android

Tags: android

I have a feature that uses the front camera of the phone. I realised that we ought to use `android.hardware.Camera2`

I Added `<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera2"/>`
Implemented the Functionality using `TextureView` which works fine on the Nexus 6P.

But when I created a signed build from this, I get "0 supported devices" in the Google Play Console.

As soon as I commented the `<uses-feature>` in Android Manifest and created the build I saw "12K supported devices".

What is going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html#features-reference there doesn't appear to be a feature **android.hardware.camera2**. This is probably why you have 0. You should just use `<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"/>`.

Comment: Yes this seems like it was it. I used the reference from here https://inducesmile.com/android/android-camera2-api-example-tutorial/ which had it wrong. I am still wondering why would it work on a Nexus 6P all fine though. should this not be a compilation error?

Comment: No, the feature selection is purely filtering for the Play store: basically if you add a `<uses-feature>` to your manifest the Play store won't show your app to any device that doesn't advertise support for said feature (the reason why you got an 0: nothing advertises support for **android.hardware.camera2**).